# Rotate and scale a complete .SVG document using Python

Tags: python-2.7, svg

I have a SVG drawing (from a Building Map) and I want to rotate the complete document 90 degrees clockwise. Now, the drawing orientation is portrait, the idea is to have a landscape orientation.

Besides of this, I would like to scale the complete document (so including all elements).

For now, I could not find the possibilties for doing this on the web. So that is why I am asking overhere. My questions are:

1. Is it possible?
2. If yes, in what way can this be done? And who wants to help with this issue.

Comment: Apply a rotate/scale transform to the SVG

Comment: @RobertLongson. Is there a standard program rule for this?

Comment: I think he is talking about doing this with CSS transform in a browser. But if I understood you correctly, this is not what you want. Perhaps you should check this module https://github.com/btel/svg_utils

Comment: CSS or SVG attribute transform. Is this a programming question at all?

Comment: The browser is not really the idea indeed. I want to write a script in Python where I import the SVG drawing, then scale and rotate the document and export it again.

Answer (score 9):

I managed to rotate an SVG figure with [svgutils](https://github.com/btel/svg_utils). It can be installed from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/svgutils/),

```
pip install svgutils
```

```py
import svgutils
svg = svgutils.transform.fromfile('camera.svg')
originalSVG = svgutils.compose.SVG('camera.svg')
originalSVG.rotate(90)
originalSVG.move(svg.height, 10)
figure = svgutils.compose.Figure(svg.height, svg.width, originalSVG)
figure.save('svgNew.svg')
```

Note that `width` and `height` attributes must be specified in original svg file in `svg` tag.

Actually, this method didn't do anything with elements except wrapping them all with `g` tag with `transform` attribute. But it seems that with this module you can access each and every element in SVG tree and do whatever you want with them.

Scaling an SVG is also easy:

```py
originalSVG.scale(2)
figure = svgutils.compose.Figure(float(svg.height) * 2, float(svg.width) * 2, originalSVG)
figure.save('svgNew.svg')
```