# Jupyter notebook how to scale an svg image?

Tags: python, svg, jupyter-notebook

I am trying and failing to load an svg image into a jupyter notebook and scaling up the dimensions.

This is what I have that displays a correct image:

```py
pathlib.Path("Documentation").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
image_path = os.path.join("Documentation", "SphereGrid")
c.writeSVGfile(image_path)

svg_file = image_path + '.svg'
display(SVG(image_path + ".svg"))
```

Which shows this:

[image]

That's super tiny.

I tried scaling it up like this:

```py
svg_file = image_path + '.svg'
import svgutils
svg = svgutils.transform.fromfile(svg_file)
original = svgutils.compose.SVG(svg_file)
original.scale(10.0)
original.moveto(-100.0, -10.0)

new_svg = svgutils.compose.Figure(float(100) * 10.0,
                                  float(100) * 10.0, original)
new_svg.save(svg_file)

display(SVG(image_path + ".svg"))
```

But that gives this:

[image]

Now the figure is the correct size but it's cropped.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43199869/rotate-and-scale-a-complete-svg-document-using-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rotate and scale a complete .SVG document using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43199869/rotate-and-scale-a-complete-svg-document-using-python)